# Mean value Theorem with two values of d

Tags: calculus

$f$ is a continuous continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$.

(a) There exists $d_1 < d_2$ in (0,1) such that $ \frac{1}{f'(d_1)}+\frac{1}{f'(d_2)}=2$

(b) There exists $d_1 < d_2$ in (0,1) such that $f'(d_1).f'(d_2) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

(a) By IVT, there exists a d in the interval (0,1) such that f(d) = 0.5 
This is because f(0) = 0 < 0.5
f(1) = 1 > 0.5

Now, by MVT, there exists a $c_1$ in the interval $(0,c_1)$ such that $f'(c_1)=\frac{f(d) - f(0)}{d - 0}$. Similarly, there exists a $c_2$ in the interval $(c_1,1)$ such that $f'(c_2)=\frac{f(1) - f(d)}{1 - d}$.

When u evaluate the required expression, the $d$ should cancel and you shld be able to obtain 2.

(b) Use IVT. In this case, it is the solution to $f(x) = 1 - x$. (Which means $f(d) = 1 - d$). You shld be able to continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

For (b), we know $f'$ achieves the value 1 at least once, say at $f'(x_1)$. If $f'$ achieves this value more than once, then we are done. If not, then since derivatives have the intermediate value property (Darboux's theorem), the derivative must be either less than 1 in $(0,x_1)$ and greater than 1 in $(x_1,1)$ or vice versa. WLOG suppose it is the former (less than on the left, greater than on the right).

Choose a point $x_0 \in (0,x_1)$ and $x_2 \in (x_1,1)$. If $f'(x_0)f'(x_2)=1$ we're done. If not, WLOG say $f'(x_0)f'(x_2)>1$. This means $1 < \frac{1}{f'(x_0)} < f'(x_2)$. Therefore, again since derivatives satisfy intermediate value property, we can find an $x_3 \in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f'(x_3)=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$. Then using $x_0$ and $x_3$ as $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively, we are done.